# How to write data and generate CSV, then send as attachment through email?

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv, email-attachments

I have a table which has 6 column.

I want write into CSV and email as attachment.

How to I make it?

```
-(void)generateCSV
{
//create instance of NSFileManager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Document Dir: %@",documentsDirectory);

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv", @"userdata"]]; //add our file to the path
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:[@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (file)

surveyarray = [db retrieveSurvey];
CHCSVWriter * csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:fullPath atomic:NO];
NSInteger numberOfColumns = 5;
for (NSInteger currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [surveyarray count]; currentIndex++) {
    id field = [surveyarray objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
    [csvWriter writeField:field];
    if ((currentIndex % numberOfColumns) == (numberOfColumns - 1)) {
        [csvWriter writeLine];
    }
}
[csvWriter release];
}
```

This is my current function. Where can I find my csv file or does it generated?

Comment: Have you tried anything? We aren't going to just do it for you. Start googling the steps one by one and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

One of your questions seems to be where do i find files i write: In answer to that question, you are saving files to the documents directory of your app if they are being saved. you can check this by enabling file sharing to itunes so that you can see that directory in itunes. for instructions on how to do this you can look here.

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/using-uifilesharingenabled-for-creating-debug-log-files.html